# How to add a column to datagrid using an object of a class, where datagrid already have columns created using a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to split the column creation of a datagrid partially in c# coee and partially in xaml code. my datagrid holds columns starting from 1 - 100 ,which are created using a list in c#.
Now i want to add columns in datagrid whose source is an object field of a class which have 30 properties. Please refer the code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Test> listTest;
    Test obj;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public List<Test> ListTest
    {
        get
        {
            return listTest;
        }
        set
        {
            listTest = value;

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listTest = new List<Test>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            obj = new Test();
            listTest.Add(obj);

        }

        this.MyDatagrid.ItemsSource = ListTest; //creating columns in datagrid by list
    }


}


public class Test
{

    public string m_field1_Test{get;set;}
    public string m_field2_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field3_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field4_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field5_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field6_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field7_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field8_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field9_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field10_Test { get; set; }
    public Test1 test1obj { get; set; }

   public Test()
    {
        m_field1_Test = "field1";
        m_field2_Test = "field2";
        m_field3_Test = "field3";
        m_field4_Test = "field4";
        m_field5_Test = "field5";
        m_field6_Test = "field6";
        m_field7_Test = "field7";
        m_field8_Test = "field8";
        m_field9_Test = "field9";
        m_field10_Test = "field10";
        test1obj = new Test1();

    }

}

public class Test1
{

    public string m_field1_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field2_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field3_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field4_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field5_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field6_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field7_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field8_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field9_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field10_Test1 { get; set; }



    public string m_field11_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field12_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field13_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field14_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field15_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field16_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field17_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field18_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field19_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field20_Test1 { get; set; }


    public string m_field21_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field22_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field23_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field24_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field25_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field26_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field27_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field28_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field29_Test1 { get; set; }
    public string m_field30_Test1 { get; set; }


    public Test1()
    {

        m_field1_Test1 = "field1";
        m_field2_Test1 = "field2";
        m_field3_Test1 = "field3";
        m_field4_Test1 = "field4";
        m_field5_Test1 = "field5";
        m_field6_Test1 = "field6";
        m_field7_Test1 = "field7";
        m_field8_Test1 = "field8";
        m_field9_Test1 = "field9";
        m_field10_Test1 = "field10";


        m_field11_Test1 = "field11";
        m_field12_Test1 = "field12";
        m_field13_Test1 = "field13";
        m_field14_Test1 = "field14";
        m_field15_Test1 = "field15";
        m_field16_Test1 = "field16";
        m_field17_Test1 = "field17";
        m_field18_Test1 = "field18";
        m_field19_Test1 = "field19";
        m_field20_Test1 = "field20";




        m_field21_Test1 = "field21";
        m_field22_Test1 = "field22";
        m_field23_Test1 = "field23";
        m_field24_Test1 = "field24";
        m_field25_Test1 = "field25";
        m_field26_Test1 = "field26";
        m_field27_Test1 = "field27";
        m_field28_Test1 = "field28";
        m_field29_Test1 = "field29";
        m_field30_Test1 = "field30";
    }



}
```

Now i want to display these 30 fields of Test1 class as the columns of datagrid. I already know that this can be done in c# code using LINQ. But in that case i have to create a new list which will have all items of list as well as fields of object. I want to know a way out by which i dnt have to manually do that.
Can somebody know the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to bind your List to your DataGrid.
I'll also recommend the [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) to make your app design simplier.

Comment: I know this can be done through binding but i need to bind secondary level fields of an object in datagrid.

Comment: okay, now i understand your problem (Test and Test1 arent the best names for examples). I wrote a new solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To programatically add a column:

```
 DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn(); 
 textColumn.Header = "First Name"; 
 textColumn.Binding = new Binding("FirstName"); 
 dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```

Check out [this post](http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/34065) on the WPF DataGrid discussion board for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution called Reflection!

Lets say you have a class called Bar:

```
public class Bar
{
    string bar1 = "bar1", bar2 = "bar2", bar3 = "bar3";

    public string Bar1
    {
        get { return bar1; }
        set { bar1 = value; }
    }

    public string Bar2
    {
        get { return bar2; }
        set { bar2 = value; }
    }

    public string Bar3
    {
        get { return bar3; }
        set { bar3 = value; }
    }

}
```

and a class called Foo which has an instance of Bar:

```
public class Foo
{
    string foo1 = "foo1", foo2 = "foo2", foo3 = "foo3";
    Bar bar1 = new Bar();

    public Bar Bar1
    {
        get { return bar1; }
        set { bar1 = value; }
    }
    public string Foo1
    {
        get { return foo1; }
        set { foo1 = value; }
    }

    public string Foo2
    {
        get { return foo2; }
        set { foo2 = value; }
    }

    public string Foo3
    {
        get { return foo3; }
        set { foo3 = value; }
    }

}
```

and on your Form1 you have a datagridview (i dont post the code of the designer), then you can do it with reflection (the code is unslightly written in Form1)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Foo> foo = new List<Foo>();

    public List<Foo> Foo
    {
        get { return foo; }
        set { foo = value; }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foo.Add(new WindowsFormsApplication1Foo());
        foo.Add(new WindowsFormsApplication1.Foo());

        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = Foo;
        dataGridView1.DataSourceChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Foo.ToArray();
    }
    bool sourceChange = true;
    void dataGridView1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGridView)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
            if (sourceChange)
            {
                sourceChange = false;
                object source = dgv.DataSource;
                Type sourceType = source.GetType();
                if (sourceType.IsArray)
                {
                    Array arr = (Array)source;
                    if (arr.Length > 0)
                    {
                        Type elementType = sourceType.GetElementType();
                        Type myType = CreateCustomType(elementType);
                        List<object> list = new List<object>();

                        IEnumerator enumerator = arr.GetEnumerator();
                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            object myNewTypeInstance=null;
                            CopyData(enumerator.Current, myType,ref myNewTypeInstance);
                            list.Add(myNewTypeInstance);
                        }
                        dgv.DataSource = list;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void CopyData(object oldObj, Type newType,ref object newObj)
    {
        if(newObj==null)
            newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);
        Type oldType = oldObj.GetType();
        foreach (var item in oldType.GetProperties())
        {
            string name = item.Name;
            object value = oldType.GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(oldObj,null);
            if (item.PropertyType.Namespace != "System")
            {
                CopyData(value, newType,ref newObj);
            }
            else
            {
                newType.GetProperty(name).SetValue(newObj, value, null);
            }
        }
    }
    private Type CreateCustomType(Type t)
    {
        AppDomain myDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
        AssemblyName myAsmName = new AssemblyName() { Name = "MyDynamicAssembly" };
        AssemblyBuilder myAsmBuilder = myDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAsmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder myModBuilder = myAsmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(myAsmName.Name, myAsmName.Name + ".dll");
        TypeBuilder myTypeBuilder = myModBuilder.DefineType("MyDynamicClass", TypeAttributes.Public);
        DefineProperties(myTypeBuilder, t);
        return myTypeBuilder.CreateType();
    }
    private void DefineProperties(TypeBuilder tBuilder, Type t)
    {
        MethodAttributes getSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
        foreach (var item in t.GetProperties())
        {
            Type _t = item.PropertyType;
            if (_t.Namespace != "System")
            {
                DefineProperties(tBuilder, _t);
            }
            else
            {
                FieldBuilder customerNameBldr = tBuilder.DefineField("_" + item.Name, item.PropertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
                PropertyBuilder custNamePropBldr = tBuilder.DefineProperty(item.Name, System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, item.PropertyType, null);

                MethodBuilder custNameGetPropMthdBldr = tBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + item.Name, getSetAttr, item.PropertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
                ILGenerator custNameGetIL = custNameGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
                custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, customerNameBldr);
                custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                MethodBuilder custNameSetPropMthdBldr = tBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + item.Name, getSetAttr,null, new Type[] { item.PropertyType });
                ILGenerator custNameSetIL = custNameSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
                custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, customerNameBldr);
                custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                custNamePropBldr.SetGetMethod(custNameGetPropMthdBldr);
                custNamePropBldr.SetSetMethod(custNameSetPropMthdBldr);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Sure, you can write it more generic, but it should show you how you could create a "dynamic type" in C#. 
Additionally I copy the data of the old structure into the new one and change the datasource to the new list of my dynamic type. Thats all ;)

If you have further questions, i'll try to help you.

The result:
[image]